# How to use addforce on a 2d object to move it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to move a 2d ball around using the arrows keys right and left. However when i click the right one the ball sometimes goes to the left and so on... And yes, i'm using Rigibody2D to do this.

```
 if (Input.GetKeyDown("right"))
    {
        bola.AddForce(transform.right * velocity,ForceMode2D.Force);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("left"))
    {
        bola.AddForce(-transform.right * velocity,ForceMode2D.Force);
    }
```

Comment: twice ? No man, apparently in c# there isn't a transform.left, so i have to put a - on it...

Comment: `Vector3.right` probably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your balls are rotating because of the force you apply and hence you use local right, the direction changes with the rotation. You should try to deactivate rigidbody rotation, or use global directions.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("right"))
{
    bola.AddForce(Vector2.right * velocity,ForceMode2D.Force);
}

if (Input.GetKeyDown("left"))
{
    bola.AddForce(-Vector2.right * velocity,ForceMode2D.Force);
}
```

Comment: Because transform relates to the position and orientation of the object. When you add force to sphere, the sphere starts to rotate and the rotation changes. If you rotate to far, right becomes left and left becomes right inisde its local coordinates.